# Updating many(100k+) documents in the most efficient way MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, promise

I have a function that runs periodically, that updates the `item.price` of some `Documents` in my `Prices` Collection. The `Price Collection` has 100k+ items. The function looks like this:

```
 //Just a helper function for multiple GET requests with request.
let _request = (urls, cb) => {
    let results = {}, i = urls.length, c = 0;
    handler = (err, response, body) => {
        let url = response.request.uri.href;
        results[url] = { err, response, body };

        if (++c === urls.length) {
            cb(results);
        }
    };
    while (i--) {
        request(urls[i], handler);
    }
};
// function to update the prices in our Prices collection.

const update = (cb) => {
    Price.remove({}, (err, remove) => {
        if (err) {
            return logger.error(`Error removing items...`);
        }
        logger.info(`Removed all items... Beginning to update.`);
        _request(urls, (responses) => {
            let url, response, gameid;

            for (url in responses) {
                id = url.split('/')[5].split('?')[0];
                response = responses[url];

                if (response.err) {
                    logger.error(`Error in request to ${url}: ${err}`);
                    return;
                }

                if (response.body) {
                    logger.info(`Request to ${url} successful.`)
                    let jsonResult = {};
                    try {
                        jsonResult = JSON.parse(response.body);
                    } catch (e) {
                        logger.error(`Could not parse.`);
                    }

                    logger.info(`Response body for ${id} is ${Object.keys(jsonResult).length}.`);
                    let allItemsArray = Object.keys(jsonResult).map((key, index) => {
                        return {
                            itemid: id,
                            hash_name: key,
                            price: jsonResult[key]
                        }
                    });

                    Price.insertMany(allItemsArray).then(docs => {
                        logger.info(`Saved docs for ${id}`)
                    }, (e) => {
                        logger.error(`Error saving docs.`);
                    });

                }
            }
            if (cb && typeof cb == 'function') {
                cb();
            }
        })
    });

}
```

As you can see, to avoid iterating through 100k+ Documents, and updating each and every one of them separately, I delete them all at the beginning, and just call the API that gives me these Items with prices, and use `InsertMany` to Insert all of them into my Prices Collection.

This updating process will happen every 30 minutes.

But I just now realised, what if some user wants to check the Prices and my `Prices Collection` is currently empty because it's in the middle of updating itself?

**The Question**

So do I have to iterate through all of them in order to not delete it? (Remember, there are MANY documents to be updated every 30 mins.) Or is there another solution?

Here's a picture of how my `Prices Collection` looks (there are 100k docs like these, I just want to update the price property):

[image: The Prices Collection]

**Update**:

I have re-written my `update` function a bit and now it looks like this:

```
const update = (cb = null) => {
    Price.remove({}, (err, remove) => {
        if (err) {
            return logger.error(`Error removing items...`);
        }
        logger.info(`Removed all items... Beginning to update.`);
        _request(urls, (responses) => {
            let url, response, gameid;

            for (url in responses) {
                gameid = url.split('/')[5].split('?')[0];
                response = responses[url];

                if (response.err) {
                    logger.error(`Error in request to ${url}: ${err}`);
                    return;
                }

                if (response.body) {
                    logger.info(`Request to ${url} successful.`)
                    let jsonResult = {};
                    try {
                        jsonResult = JSON.parse(response.body);
                    } catch (e) {
                        logger.error(`Could not parse.`);
                    }

                    logger.info(`Response body for ${gameid} is ${Object.keys(jsonResult).length}.`);
                    let allItemsArray = Object.keys(jsonResult).map((key, index) => {
                        return {
                            game_id: gameid,
                            market_hash_name: key,
                            price: jsonResult[key]
                        }
                    });
                    let bulk = Price.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();

                    allItemsArray.forEach(item => {
                        bulk.find({market_hash_name: item.market_hash_name})
                            .upsert().updateOne(item);
                    });
                    bulk.execute((err, bulkers) => {
                        if (err) {
                            return logger.error(`Error bulking: ${e}`);
                        }
                        logger.info(`Updated Items for ${gameid}`)
                    });

                    // Price.insertMany(allItemsArray).then(docs => {
                    //     logger.info(`Saved docs for ${gameid}`)
                    // }, (e) => {
                    //     logger.error(`Error saving docs.`);
                    // });

                }
            }
            if (cb && typeof cb == 'function') {
                cb();
            }
        })
    });

}
```

Notice the bulk variable now (Thanks @Rahul) but now, the collection takes ages to update. My processor is burning up and it literally takes 3+ minutes to update 60k+ documents. I honestly feel like the previous method, while it might delete all of them and then reinserting them, it also takes 10x faster.

Anyone?

Comment: Instead of deleting and adding data every time use bulk upsert of MongoDB, another thing is to don't complete data from the _request return in the chunk of 100/1000.

Comment: I've updated my question thanks to your comment. Care to take a look now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From my experience (updating millions of mongo docs on a hourly basis), here's a realistic approach to very large bulk updates:

- do all your API calls separately and write results in as bson into a file
- invoke `mongoimport` and import that bson file into a new empty collection `prices_new`. Javascript, let alone high-level OO wrappers, are just too slow for that
- rename `prices_new` -> `prices` `dropTarget=true` (this will be atomic hence no downtime)

Schematically, it would look like this in JS

```
let fname = '/tmp/data.bson';
let apiUrls = [...];

async function doRequest(url) {
    // perform a request and return an array of records
}

let responses  = await Promise.all(apiUrls.map(doRequest));

// if the data too big to fit in memory, use streams instead of this:

let data = flatMap(responses, BSON.serialize).join('\n'));
await fs.writeFile(fname, data);

await child_process.exec(`mongoimport --collection prices_new --drop ${fname}`);

await db.prices_new.renameCollection('prices', true);
```

Comment: I don't see how you derive "no downtime" from "atomic".

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It seems like the most efficient way to do this. Care to give an example of writing the results in to a BSON file and then importing it?

Comment: What if MongoDB is running is on another instance. That time we don't have access to BSON file, how can we handle the same situation?

Comment: @RahulSharma: you could run `mongoimport` over the network (`--host xxx` etc), or copy your bson over there once it's populated.

Comment: @georg Thanks for the answer :)

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to clear the database and do a fresh insert. You can use the **[`bulkWrite()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#bulkwrite_bulkWrite)** method for this or use the **[`updateMany()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#updatemany_updateMany)** method to do the updates.

You can refactor the existing code to

```
const update = (cb) => {
    _request(urls, responses => {
        let bulkUpdateOps = [], gameid;

        responses.forEach(url => {
            let response = responses[url];
            gameid = url.split('/')[5].split('?')[0];

            if (response.err) {
                logger.error(`Error in request to ${url}: ${response.err}`);
                return;
            }

            if (response.body) {
                logger.info(`Request to ${url} successful.`)
                let jsonResult = {};
                try {
                    jsonResult = JSON.parse(response.body);
                } catch (e) {
                    logger.error(`Could not parse.`);
                }

                Object.keys(jsonResult).forEach(key => {
                    bulkUpdateOps.push({
                        "updateOne": {
                           "filter": { market_hash_name: key },
                           "update": { "$set": {
                                game_id: gameid,
                                price: jsonResult[key]
                           } },
                           "upsert": true
                        }
                    });
                });
            }

            if (bulkUpdateOps.length === 1000) {
                Price.bulkWrite(bulkUpdateOps).then(result => {
                    logger.info(`Updated Items`)
                }).catch(e => logger.error(`Error bulking: ${e}`));
                bulkUpdateOps = [];
            }
        });

        if (bulkUpdateOps.length > 0) {
            Price.bulkWrite(bulkUpdateOps).then(result => {
                logger.info(`Updated Items`)
            }).catch(e => logger.error(`Error bulking: ${e}`));
        }
    });

    if (cb && typeof cb == 'function') {
        cb();
    }
}
```

Comment: Will this upsert the Prices if they don't exist?

Comment: @FilipBarakovski Yes, if you add the `"upsert" : true` option as in the updates above.

Answer (score 1):

I have not tested anything but you can try this, might be helpful. I am using bluebird library for concurrency.

```
let _request = (url) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        request(url, (err, response, body) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            }
            resolve(body);
        });
    });
};

const formatRespose = async (response) => {
    // do stuff
    return {
        query: {}, //  itemid: id,
        body: {}
    };
}

const bulkUpsert = (allItemsArray) => {
    let bulk = Price.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        allItemsArray.forEach(item => {
            bulk.find(item.query).upsert().updateOne(item.body);
        });
        bulk.execute((err, bulkers) => {
            if (err) {
                return reject(err);
            }
            return resolve(bulkers);
        });
    });
}


const getAndUpdateData = async (urls) => {
    const allItemsArray = urls.map((url) => {
        const requestData = await _request(url); // you can make this also parallel
        const formattedData = formatRespose(requestData); // return {query: {},body: {} };
        return formattedData;
    });
    return await (bulkUpsert(allItemsArray));
};

function update() {
    // split urls into as per your need 100/1000
    var i, j, chunkUrls = [],
        chunk = 100;
    for (i = 0, j = urls.length; i < j; i += chunk) {
        chunkUrls.push(getAndUpdateData(urls.slice(i, i + chunk)));
    }

    Bluebird.map(chunkUrls, function (chunk) {
        return await chunk;
    }, {
        concurrency: 1 // depends on concurrent request change 1 = 100 request get and insert in db at time
    }).then(function () {
        console.log("done");
    }).catch(function () {
        console.log("error");
    });
}
```